# How to speed up spark job of combinations of an array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to get all combinations of an array, as well as below, since input data scale is huge, I can't cache it in memory, do anyone know how to speed up it? Thanks in advance.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.textFile(subInputPath).filter(s => ((s != "") && (!s.isEmpty))).map(line => {
    str = line + separator
    val lineArr = line.split(separator)
    for (i<-startIndex to lineArr.length - 1) {
        for (j<-(i + 1) to lineArr.length - 1) {
            obj_i = DistributedLRFunctions.safeStringToDouble(lineArr(i))
            obj_j = DistributedLRFunctions.safeStringToDouble(lineArr(j))
            if (!obj_i.equals(None) &&
                !obj_j.equals(None))
                str = str + obj_i.get * obj_j.get + separator
            else
                str = str + missingValue + separator
        }
    }
(str.substring(0, str.length - 1))
}).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here with all the string manipulation? What is your end goal?

Comment: Each line input looks like "0.1,0.2,0.3", I need to get 0.1*0.2, 0.1*0.3, 0.2*0.3, and append it in original string